# can't make a module in freeswitch

Tags: makefile, raspberry-pi, freeswitch

**Background Information**

I am trying to follow the article listed below to make my Raspberry Pi into a PBX: (running on the wheezy Raspbian os)

http://raspberrypipbx.blogspot.ca/2012/12/using-google-voice-as-land-line.html?showComment=1394806601950#c2548040647034435813

**Problem**

I'm on the step where I'm supposed to make mod_dingaling by doing the following:

```
#make mod_dingaling-install
```

When I do that, I'm getting the following error:

> No rule to make target 'mod_dingaling-install'.

**What I've done So Far:**

I've cross referenced another article that takes you through the freeswitch install, found here: https://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Mod_dingaling

I confirmed I have the module by doing the following:

```
apt-get install libssl-dev
```

The system returns with the message that libssl-dev is already the newest version.

I'm not sure how to fix this problem. I've been googling the error message... haven't found anything relevant to me yet. But I'll keep trying. In the interim thought I'd post here to see if anyone had an idea.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Did you remove the "#" in front of "endpoints/mod_dingaling" in the "modules.conf" file?